# How to start a service with dependencies without declaring it in method arguments?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Good day.
I want to run in a controller method a class whose name comes through arguments.
The class exists, inherits the desired interface, and is perfectly created via new.

```
public function indexAction ($class) {
    if (
        ! empty ($class)
        && class_exists ($class)
        && in_array (DirectPerformerInterface::class, class_implements ($class))
    ) {
        /** @var DirectPerformerInterface $obj */
        $obj = new $class;
        $response = $obj->run();
    }
}
```

Everything is working.
But in the constructor, the class being launched may have dependencies. Accordingly, with new, they must be passed explicitly (and the classes may be different) or try to somehow run it through dependencies. In theory, the controller should have had enough:

```
        /** @var DirectPerformerInterface $obj */
        $obj = $this->get($class);
```

however, I have an error:

```
Service "class name" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside "***\Controller\DirectPerformerController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine", "form.factory", " http_kernel "," parameter_bag "," request_stack "," router "," security.authorization_checker "," security.csrf.token_manager "," security.token_storage "," serializer "," session "," templating "and" twig " services. Try using dependency injection instead.
```

the same if `$obj = $this->container->get($class);`
The documentation doesn't give the right answer (probably because I can't ask the right question).

Please help me

Comment: The AbstractController receives a service locator instead of the global container.  The naming is confusing but only a handful of services are accessible through the service locator.  But even if you had the global container, Symfony defines services as private by default so you would get a different error message but the same disappointing result.  I have no idea what you are trying to actually do but if it involves pulling services directly from the container then it is probably the wrong approach.

Comment: I need this approach to "quickly" solve emerging problems. If there is no need to write a class in all instances, then it can be quickly created on any device and quickly loaded through the web interface. I pressed the button - the code was executed. Otherwise, you will need to fully execute git code and install composer, which requires console input, which means I need to be in the office.